# VS2013 Project properties settings missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, properties, project

After Windows did a update yesterday the project properties settings are missing in VS2013
Please see the image below.

???

[image: Screenshot of project properties]

Comment: My mistake. I have a C# project. There wouldn't show Linker-settings

Comment: can you post what you mean as an answer ? It may be useful for others in future.